# Tela deixa de responder após clicar em um dos botões

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo um programa simples de jogo da velha junto ao Swing. Queria saber por qual motivo, ao disparar um evento de clicar pelo método `ActionPerfomed`, o meu programa congela. Fui pesquisar um pouco e me deparei que esses são problemas normais de interface por causa da Thread de execução. Se alguém puder explicar o erro e por que isso acontece ficaria grato.

**Classe de comparação e  inserção de valores**

```
public class JogoVelha {

private int [][] tabuleiro = new int[3][3];

public int[][] getTabuleiro()
{
   return this.tabuleiro;
}

//Seta valores do tabuleiro

public void setTabuleiroValor(int posicaoLinha,int posicaoColuna,int 
jogador)
{
   this.tabuleiro[posicaoLinha][posicaoColuna] = jogador;
}

//Cria valores dos jogadores
public String  jogadores(int jogador)
{
   Map<Integer,String> jogadores = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

   jogadores.put(1, "JOGADOR 1");
   jogadores.put(2, "JOGADOR 2");

   return jogadores.get(jogador); 
}

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 public boolean  verificarPartida(int [][] tabuleiro,int jogador)
    {
   //compara os valores da linha/coluna

    for(int i = 0; i <2;i++)
    {
       if( tabuleiro[0][i] == jogador && tabuleiro[1][i] == jogador && 
       tabuleiro[2][i] == jogador)
       {
       return true;
       }
       continue;
   }

   //compara os valores  coluna/ linha

   for(int i= 0;i<2;i++)
   {
       if(tabuleiro[i][0] == jogador && tabuleiro[i][1] == jogador && 
       tabuleiro[i][2] == jogador)
       {
       return true;
       }
       continue;
   }

   //Comparar os valores das linhas que interceptam no meio
   if(tabuleiro[0][0] == jogador && tabuleiro[1][1] == jogador 
   &&tabuleiro[2][2] == jogador)
     return true;

   else if (tabuleiro[0][2] == jogador && tabuleiro[1][1] == jogador 
   &&tabuleiro[2][0] == jogador)
       return true;

   return false;
}
```

**Classe de criação do UI**

```
public class View extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static int jogadorValue = 1;
public static Integer turnos = 1; 

JLabel lblJogoVelha = new JLabel("Jogo da Velha");
JLabel lblTurno = new JLabel("Turno");
JLabel lblTurnoNumber = new JLabel();
JLabel lblAjogar= new JLabel();
JLabel lblJogador = new JLabel();

public JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
public JButton b2 = new JButton("b2");
public JButton b3 = new JButton("b3");
public JButton b4 = new JButton("b4");
public JButton b5 = new JButton("b5");
public JButton b6 = new JButton("b6");
public JButton b7 = new JButton("b7");
public JButton b8 = new JButton("b8");
public JButton b9 = new JButton("b9");





JogoVelha jogoVelha = new JogoVelha();


public void setarListener()
{
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);
}

public void adicionarViewButtons()
{
    getContentPane().add(b1);
    getContentPane().add(b2);
    getContentPane().add(b3);
    getContentPane().add(b4);
    getContentPane().add(b5);
    getContentPane().add(b6);
    getContentPane().add(b7);
    getContentPane().add(b8);
    getContentPane().add(b9);
}

public void atribuirValorTabuleiro(String name)
{
    switch(name)
    {
    case "b1":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(0, 0, jogadorValue);
          break;

    case "b2":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(0, 1, jogadorValue);
          break;

    case "b3":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(0, 2, jogadorValue);
          break;

    case "b4":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(1, 0, jogadorValue);
          break;    

    case "b5":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(1, 1, jogadorValue);
          break;          
    case "b6":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(1, 2, jogadorValue);
          break;          

    case "b7":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(2, 0, jogadorValue);
          break;          

    case "b8":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(2, 1, jogadorValue);
          break;    

    case "b9":
          jogoVelha.setTabuleiroValor(2, 2, jogadorValue);
          break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             turnos ++;
             lblTurnoNumber.setText(turnos.toString());;


             if(turnos == 10)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empate");
             }
             else
             {
                if(jogadorValue == 1)
                {

                setEnabled(false);
                atribuirValorTabuleiro(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText());
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("X");
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).revalidate();

                if(turnos >=5)
                {
                    jogoVelha.verificarPartida(jogoVelha.getTabuleiro(), jogadorValue);
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vencedor é: " + jogoVelha.jogadores(jogadorValue), "Vencedor", 3, 4);
                }
                jogadorValue ++;

                }

                else    
                {   
                     atribuirValorTabuleiro((((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()));
                    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("O");
                    ((JButton) e.getSource()).revalidate();

                    if(turnos >=5)
                    {
                        jogoVelha.verificarPartida(jogoVelha.getTabuleiro(), jogadorValue);
                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vencedor é: " + jogoVelha.jogadores(jogadorValue), "Vencedor", 3, 4);
                    }
                    jogadorValue --;

                }
            }
        }




public View()
{
    getContentPane().add(lblJogoVelha);
    getContentPane().add(lblTurno);
    getContentPane().add(lblTurnoNumber);
    this.adicionarViewButtons();
    this.setarListener();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
    lblTurnoNumber.setText(turnos.toString());
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);


}

 public static void main(String[] args){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
      View tela = new View();
      tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      tela.setVisible(true);
    }
});

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A aplicação não está travando, o problema é que você está desativando a tela no trecho abaixo, dentro do `actionPerformed()`:

```
if (jogadorValue == 1) {

    setEnabled(false);
    atribuirValorTabuleiro(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("X");
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).revalidate();

    if (turnos >= 5) {
        jogoVelha.verificarPartida(jogoVelha.getTabuleiro(), jogadorValue);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vencedor é: " + jogoVelha.jogadores(jogadorValue), "Vencedor",
                3, 4);
    }
    jogadorValue++;

}
```

Remova esse `setEnabled(false)` que tudo volta a funcionar sem "travar" a tela.

---

Creio que valha a pena alertar quanto a essa linha também:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vencedor é: " + jogoVelha.jogadores(jogadorValue),
 "Vencedor", 3, 4);
```

Além desse método não parecer adequado para isso, já que o [`showConfirmDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-) abre uma janela modal para confirmar algum questionamento e não há nenhum ai, você está passando valores inválidos.

Os dois últimos parâmetros recebidos por este método se referem a:

- `optionType` -  representa justamente as opções de botões disponíveis pro usuario clicar conforme o questionamento, e os valores válidos são `YES_NO_OPTION`, `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`, ou `OK_CANCEL_OPTION`. Nenhuma dessas constantes vale 3.
- `messageType`- representa o tipo de mensagem exibida. Os valores válidos são: `ERROR_MESSAGE`, `INFORMATION_MESSAGE`, `WARNING_MESSAGE`, `QUESTION_MESSAGE`, ou `PLAIN_MESSAGE`. Nenhuma delas valem 4.

Sempre leia a documentação para evitar problemas desse tipo. Tudo isso que expliquei está lá.

Há outros problemas no código, mas não fazem parte do foco da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado Articuno,se quiser citar sobre os outros problemas do programa estou aberto a criticas =)

Comment: @DiogoMartinsSilva são mais problemas voltados a lógica, como o if desse joptionpane que citei, você considera que 5 jogadas é fim de jogo, mas está errado. O minimo de movimentos possiveis para alguém vencer o jogo é justamente 5, e o jogo está entrando nesse if antes de alguém poder vencer. E creio que essa lógica está errada, você não pode usar a quantidade de turnos pra avaliar se a partida chegou ao fim, da uma pesquisada sobre tic tac toe pra ver como funciona a lógica de um verdadeiro jogo da velha.

Comment: Opa me desculpe,eu já arrumei essa parte.A comparação e para ver se esta no 5 turno(porque somente nesse turno adiante algum jogador pode ganhar),coloquei a função de verificar dentro de um novo if,e deixei assim pois não queria que ele fosse executado antes desse turno (porque na função de verificar tem alguns laços de repetição).

Comment: @DiogoMartinsSilva ainda sim a lógica está ruim. Veja esse link aqui: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166209/tic-tac-toe-in-swing

Comment: Eu tinha feito bem parecido na minha primeira tentativa,só que não estava conseguindo resgatar o valor do objeto  para setar os valores(depois fui ver que era só fazer um cast de jbutton na variável do evento,faz tempo que não mexo com manipulação de objetos visuais ).E sim ficou bem falho nessa parte de simplesmente comparar o texto para setar os valores e o fato de eu não utilizar um laço para criar os botões.Obrigado por tudo e abraço o/